# Why can't apt-get find the PyCoral Debian package?

Tags: google-coral

I am trying to install PyCoral API on my Coral Dev Board which is running Mendel Linux V4.0. According to the Coral web page:
"https://coral.ai/software/#pycoral-api"

the instruction to install is:
"sudo apt-get install python3-pycoral"

But the response is:
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pycoral"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is that I am following instructions that are out of date.

FTR: I am running terminal on macOS 12.3 and using mendel tools to ssh to the Coral Dev Board (mdt shell).

So I am trying to install onto the Coral Dev Board running Mendel Debian Linux 4.0 from instructions at the Coral site I show above, after activating the virtual environment in which python3.7.3 is the default I used the instructions on the same web page "for other systems" and used pip, as follows:

(P3.7.3)~$ python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral~=2.0
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/
Collecting pycoral~=2.0
Downloading https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/releases/download/v2.0.0/pycoral-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl (352 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 352.3/352.3 kB 4.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.0 in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pycoral~=2.0) (1.21.6)
Collecting Pillow>=4.0.0
Downloading Pillow-9.2.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl (3.1 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.1/3.1 MB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tflite-runtime==2.5.0.post1
Downloading https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/releases/download/v2.0.0/tflite_runtime-2.5.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl (1.3 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.3/1.3 MB 6.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: tflite-runtime, Pillow, pycoral
Successfully installed Pillow-9.2.0 pycoral-2.0.0 tflite-runtime-2.5.0.post1

Then:
(P3.7.3)~$ pip list
Package               Version

---

numpy                 1.21.6
opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66
Pillow                9.2.0
pip                   22.2.2
pkg_resources         0.0.0
pycoral               2.0.0
setuptools            40.8.0
tflite-runtime        2.5.0.post1

This appears to be success!

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you need to add the PPA to your apt get package repo list, instructions for that are here:

https://coral.ai/software/#debian-packages